# Implementation of isEmpty()

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, is-empty

I'm trying to figure some basic things out. I was exploring standard library ArrayList.java when found that ArrayList has implementation of method isEmpty().

ArrayList.java:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}
```

ArrayList extends AbstractList extends AbstractCollection. And AbstractCollection has implementation of isEmpty as well:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size() == 0;
}
```

I'm just trying to get the logic? Why ArrayList implements already implemented method? What for?

P.S. ArrayList also has size

```
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Probably to cut out the unnecessary method call.

Comment: Because not every collection provides a local `size` field, and it's a *specialization* (or *optimization*) available in this case.

Comment: Efficiency and self-awareness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ArrayList version is a minor, but effective, optimisation.

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: How do you actually view the ArrayList class in eclipse?  Is it somewhere in library?

Comment: Well, I guess I figured it out now, thanks! Nick Ziebert, I was watching declarations of all I saw on screen with Alt + B.